# Meta SO - Activity Tag - Reputation

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, meta

Today when i check meta SO , under Activity tag my reputation shows as 1495 + 1.4k , as the following screenshot

[image]

I didn't understand the meaning.Someone please explain ?

Comment: Hint: Hover over the green number, and see what the tooltip says.

Comment: That was actually from mobile.Now the green number disappeared.Could you please explain?

Comment: The tooltip is "reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab".