# Why do I have 12K rep increase on my profile in Meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web

Since this is a per-site Meta, we're not supposed to get reputation here.

*But*, I couldn't help but notice this while on my mobile phone.

[image]

Looking at it from my browser, I can see this element present in the mobile view:

```
<span class="rep-increase" 
      title="Reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab"
      tabindex="12046">
          +12k
</span>
```

I already know that Meta keeps track of "reputation" so that we may be awarded rep-based participation badges like Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary.  But I suppose there are two things wrong here:

- This tag really shouldn't be appearing on the mobile view when it's not present on the desktop view, and
- There's no reputation tab for me to visit here, so I can't get rid of it on Meta.  *Ever.*

I'm hoping that someone on the formal development team (hey Jin - got a sec?) could weigh in.

Comment: Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. :)

Comment: How strange, it's the same for me but says `+15.9k` (i.e. ALL of my rep!) and is only present on the mobile view. You can test this by clicking the 'mobile' link in the page footer.

Comment: Also just spotted [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290541/meta-so-activity-tag-reputation) which appears to be a duplicate with a slightly incorrect answer (which is why I won't VTC this question)

Comment: I see this only in the mobile version: `+683`, which is all the reputation I have earned since the first day, according to www.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: I am also able to replicate  this. Seems a straight-forward bug.

Comment: You must have meta'd so hard

Comment: Seriously though, this isn't a dupe.  The other question is asking, "What does this mean?", and I'm stating, "This is wrong and broken because we don't have rep here and I can never reset it and it only ever applies to the mobile view."

Comment: If you don't want **Just Give me** @Makoto

Comment: @MD You can have all of my meta rep! :P

Comment: This actually seems like a useful bug, if it displays your net meta reputation.

Comment: @Yakk, But my meta rep seems to be always the same as my main rep, so it's useless (for me anyway).

Comment: I wonder why the first comment has more votes than the question .. ? If you can vote a funny comment, why not vote for the question as well.

Comment: You know this question is just making the problem worse...that 12K just keeps on growing.

Comment: @JonasCz ah: I cannot reproduce it, so I thought the green number was your 'actual meta rep', while the other number was your SO rep.

Comment: @EricJ. I guess we could all help him out by downvoting. :)

Comment: @reirab: If exactly enough of us do that, we could even solve the problem for him :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't want to appear biased about this question, but I'm wondering about what you have just done here (casting a binding close vote then single-handedly reopening the question, therefore nuking three pending close votes from users before they expire naturally). Are you supposed to do that? Is that considered fair game wrt the other close voters? (It's actually the first time I've seen a moderator doing this.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: they were dupe votes to a question already closed in this direction. You cannot cast additional dupe votes *anyway*. There was no point in leaving them around.

Comment: @Martijn, ah, I see, thank you for your reply. From the post history, it *looked* like these users had voted to close the question as "unclear what you're asking", but I guess that was your binding vote. There is unfortunately no hint those were duplicate close votes, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered you. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: I noticed that some SE sites did this to me and some did not.

Comment: This is a duplicate based on your logic from other questions.

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  Also how is it possible that it's a duplicate from what my other questions state?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This bug was overlooked when fixing on the main, non-mobile display.

Fixed in the next build, which will be going out shortly.