# Reputation icon next to the "top tag" icon does not go away when you visit the reputation tab

Tags: bug, user-interface

On the user summary page there is a "top tag" section that tells you what your top tag is and any recent reputation gained on that tag since your last visit to the reputation tab.

[image]

When you hover over the +10, the tooltip states that it shows the reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab; however going to the reputation tab and then back to the summary doesn't appear to clear the +10 notification.

Very minor bug, but still a bug (or just a grammar mistake) nonetheless.

Comment: I searched, but I didn't find it.  If it has just let me know and I will take my post down.

Comment: Well, possibly related: [This fixed bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291482/why-do-i-have-12k-rep-increase-on-my-profile-in-meta).  It has the status complete tag, so I'm not sure if it's the same problem or what.

Comment: Possibly related, but its doubtful that they are the same bug since that one was fixed and I am experiencing this one today (3 months later).

Comment: Came here to post the same bug, happens to me as well.